# Why is my jest test failing for URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, createobjecturl

I have two unit tests like so:

```js
test('should call downloadPDFFile with msSaveOrOpenBlob when the navigator is present', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: 'blob' });
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob = () => true;
  const msSaveOrOpenBlobSpy = jest.spyOn(window.navigator, 'msSaveOrOpenBlob');
  await downloadPDFFile('www.pokebook/{+asset_path}', 'squirtle', '123', false);
  expect(msSaveOrOpenBlobSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('blob', 'squirtle.pdf');
});

test('should call downloadPDFFile with createObjectURL when the navigator is not present', async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: 'blob' });
  window.URL.createObjectURL = () => 'www.pokeball.com';
  console.log(window.navigator);
  const urlCreateObjectSpy = jest.spyOn(window.URL, 'createObjectURL');
  await downloadPDFFile('www.pokebook/{+asset_path}', 'charmander', '123', false);
  expect(urlCreateObjectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('blob');
});
```

And after reading many posts, it seems like `window.URL.createObjectURL = () => {};` should work, however, I keep running into this test failure message on the **second** one:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "blob"

    Number of calls: 0

      557 |             const urlCreateObjectSpy = jest.spyOn(window.URL, 'createObjectURL');
      558 |             await downloadPDFFile('www.pokebook/{+asset_path}', 'charmander', '123', false);
    > 559 |             expect(urlCreateObjectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('blob');
          |                                        ^
      560 |         });
      561 |     });
      562 | });
```

Here is the function being tested:

```js
const downloadPDFFile = (urlTemplate, name, readToken, isWatermarked) => {
  const config = { responseType: "blob" };
  const pdfFileName = `${name.split(".")[0]}.pdf`;
  let formattedUrl;

  if (isWatermarked) {
    formattedUrl = urlTemplate.replace("{+temp}?", `?token=${readToken}&`);
  } else {
    formattedUrl = urlTemplate.replace("{+temp}", `?token=${readToken}`);
  }

  axios.get(formattedUrl, config).then((response) => {
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(response.data, pdfFileName);
    } else {
      const anchor = document.createElement("a");
      anchor.download = pdfFileName;
      anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
      document.body.appendChild(anchor);
      anchor.click();
      document.body.removeChild(anchor);
    }
  });
};
```

Am I missing some kind of a cleanup step in between tests? (the console.log in the second test shows that the window.navigator object is actually defined, which I suspect is why I'm getting strange behavior)

Comment: @Phil Updated and removed!

Comment: Sorry, could you please re-add the bit of code this is testing?

Comment: Thank you for the edit! Apparently formatting code on a phone is more difficult than I thought 

Comment: Does it make a difference if your code uses `window.URL.createObjectURL` instead of `URL.createObjectURL`?

Comment: Unfortunately it results in the same failure message :(

Comment: @Phil Updated my question above! I think I'm missing some kind of a cleanup step...

Comment: I'd say so. You should probably delete `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` after that first test runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that I was forgetting to do a cleanup step after my previous test; in my first test I set `window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob` which is what I wanted/expected. But this carried over into the second test which caused unexpected results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you don't return `axios.get().then()`, so `downloadPDFFile()` returns `undefined` and `await` has no effect, leading to `expect(urlCreateObjectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("blob");` being called before `anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);`

Just update this line to add `return`

```js
  return axios.get(formattedUrl, config).then((response) => {
```

---

Alternatively, you can make the function asynchronous

```js
const downloadPDFFile = async (urlTemplate, name, readToken, isWatermarked) => {
```

and then use the `await` syntax

```js
  const response = await axios.get(formattedUrl, config);
  if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(response.data, pdfFileName);
  } else {
    const anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.download = pdfFileName;
    anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
    document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    anchor.click();
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
  }
```

Comment: Hm, tried both ways and I still got the `Number of calls: 0` failure message. Do I also need to change something in the unit test??

Comment: I updated my question above! It seems like I'm missing a cleanup step somewhere..